# how to show image in listview builder from database

Tags: mysql, flutter, image, dart, listview

please help me I want to show image in listview constructor, image name i stored in database. My image file is stored in Folders Pictures. I retrieve the image to display in the listview builder but the image is not displayed. It seems the code cannot find the image file I have stored in Folders Pictures. What do I need to fix to get the image to show?
[image]

```
class _view_problemState extends State<view_problem> {
  TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();

  List<problemModel> problemlist = [];
  List<problemModel> originalList = [];
  StreamController _streamController = StreamController();
  Future getAllProblem() async {
    problemlist = await problemcontrollers().getProblem();
    originalList = problemlist;
    _streamController.sink.add(problemlist);
  }
Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: _streamController.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshots) {
                  if (snapshots.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: problemlist.length,
                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                          problemModel problem = problemlist[index];
                          return Card(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.network(
                                problem.image,
                                height: 55,
                                width: 55,
                              ),
                                title: Text(
                                problem.name_surname,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19),
                              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Place your images in `assets` folder
2. Then make changes in `pubspec.yaml` file to access the images from the assets folder like this.

   ```
   assets:
     - 'your_folder_name/'
   ```
3. Then where you want to display the image

   ```
   StreamBuilder(
            stream: _streamController.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshots) {
              if (snapshots.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: problemlist.length,
                    itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                      problemModel problem = problemlist[index];
                      return Card(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: Image.network(
                            "assets/" + problem.image,
                            height: 55,
                            width: 55,
                          ),
                            title: Text(
                            problem.name_surname,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19),
                          ),
   ```

now you will be able to display image like this

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting. But I don't store the images in the assets folder. I keep the images in the folder. image_Pictures
How do I access images from content folders like this?

Comment: Yes you can specify your folder name in place of assets below assets in pubspec.yaml file

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display images from your api data. So you have to try Image.network in this way.

```js
Image.network(
  problem.image,
  width: 55,
  height: 55,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
    ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
      if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
        return Center(
          child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
        );
    },
),
```